# Запятая В ТОМ(,) ЧТОБЫ

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться со знаками препинания в предложении:

> Срединный путь в данном случае — в том, чтобы оживлять осознавание,
>   при этом его не возбуждая.

Насколько понимаю, тире в данном случае заменяет пропущенное сказуемое и ставится как интонационное при наличии паузы (переводчик поставил, поэтому исхожу из того, что интонационная пауза есть).
Вопрос: если тире оставить, требуется ли запятая перед "чтобы"? Или в этом случае союз "в том чтобы" будет относиться полностью к придаточной части и запятая не нужна? Создается такое впечатление, что необходимо оставить либо тире, либо запятую.
Буду очень признательна за ответ и пояснения!
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Срединный путь в данном случае — в том, чтобы оживлять осознавание, при этом его не возбуждая.**

Знаки препинания расставлены верно. Интонационное тире необходимо на месте возможного сказуемого (состоит, заключается).

Запятая ставится пред **изъяснительным союзом ЧТОБЫ** (придаточное изъяснительное раскрывает содержание указательного слова *в том*).

**Примечание**

Изъяснительный союз ЧТОБЫ надо отличать от целевого союза ЧТОБЫ, который образует с местоимением составные союзы (они могут расчленяться или не расчленяться), например:  *Компания передала новые разработки самолета, с тем чтобы потом организовать  совместное производство.*

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу прочитать это предложение, не сделав акцента (ударения) на "том". (Похожий случай с "потому что": если делают ударение на "потому", то ставят запятую не перед всем оборотом, а между частями.) Поэтому запятую я бы оставил. Насчёт тире не скажу уверенно, но, если надо убрать один из знаков, я бы убрал тире.